# Search multiple keywords and give them correct number

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there any formula to search keywords in cells? I mean I've got something like this:

number 1: stack, overflow
number 2: google, sheets

And I have a cell containing a string "stackisok". And next to this cell there should be shown a number which corresponds to the keyword which was found, so there should be "number 1". Is it possible using Google Sheets?

Comment: It is certainly possible, but could you elaborate more on what would constitute a valid match?

Comment: this is not really a 'how to use a spreadsheet' site, there are many good tutorial sites. Suggest you have a read through the list of spreadsheet formulas (see the spreadsheet help menu) and find a good spreadsheet tutorial site. - good luck.

Comment: @AdamL a valid match would be when in string there is one of the keywords from concrete number, no matter if it is written in big letters, small, there are spaces or not.

It is sth like search engine. "number 1", "number 2" are categories and "stack", "overflow", "google", "sheets" are tags, and formula searches these tags in string and when finds one, it gives me correct category.

Comment: Ok. How exactly is the lookup table laid out?

Comment: @AdamL A2:A are strings where should be some tag found. B2:B is where should be shown the category of the string. E3, F3 etc are the names of categories. From E4:E are tags for category "number 1", from F4:F are tags for "number 2". I attached a link to spreadsheet and it was deleted? docs.google.[HERE SHOULD BE 'COM']/spreadsheets/d/1d-XwR-iZig9QsEmu7cYQiHEab9j8buCXbua39BfG59o/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer:

```
=arrayformula(regexreplace(transpose(substitute(trim(query(transpose(if(regexmatch(substitute(A2:A100;char(32);char(9));regexreplace(substitute(query(substitute(E4:AI106;char(32);char(9));"select*";999);char(32);"|");"\|*$";""));E3:AI3;));"select*";999));char(32);", "));"^$";"23"))
```

was given by `2n9` [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/HBiLRQyDlqw).